# What makes the player character 'different'?

Tags: the-swapper

In The Swapper, it is revealed towards the end:

> that you the player, are a clone of the Scavenger, created when she first used the Swapper device at the encouragement of the two scientist-brains.

Now for whatever reason, you were jettisoned to the planet, which is where the gameplay begins. The main character (player) is independent right from the start, as you are panicking as the escape pod is launched.

So my question is: What makes you different from the others?

> If every other clone is a mindless 'chained' puppet, why are you able to act independently?

I've read all the in-game logs, I didn't notice anything that would explain this.

Comment: FYI: You shouldn't be spoilering the main body of your question.  If your question doesn't make sense without reading what's in the spoiler text, then it shouldn't be there.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of rewriting it in such a way that only the spoilerific parts are in spoiler-text. I've also removed the 'spoiler' from the title - if people are worried about spoilers, generally they won't click through (or will have the tag & questions related to it hidden). Spoilered text won't show up on the main page either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There's no precedent for what happened to your character in-universe.**

> If you were originally a clone of the Scavenger, after the Scavenger is "swapped" with the two scientists, there's nobody left for your clone to *clone*, or follow, as it were.

However, **the game also gives no real hint as to how this may affect your character**, or even if this is truly what differentiates your character at all, and so below are some purely theoretical events that may have taken place after the key event.

> When the consciousnesses were merged, perhaps the link between the original and you are severed, resulting in **A) another version of the Scavenger**, trying to finish what they originally started on the derelict vessel, **B) an original consciousness potentially based on the Scavenger in some way**, affected by the memory loss mentioned in-game and trying to figure out who they are and what to do, or or **C) an (almost) empty shell being influenced by the Watchers**, trying to get those on the ship to reunite with their brethren on the planet and finally giving the character the choice to live their own life or join the rest of the Watcher's consciousness.

Hopefully this is at least somewhat satisfactory!